# javascript pass html input type id to function

Tags: javascript, html, function

Suppose I have a list of the following HTML elements with a Javascript event to copy the content of the HTML input type text into the clipboard:

```
<input type="text" size="70" value="something1" id="v1">
<button onclick="CopyToClipboard('v1')">Copy command</button>

<input type="text" size="70" value="something2" id="v2">
<button onclick="CopyToClipboard('v2')">Copy command</button>
```

etc..

How do I copy the txt using javascript?

I am trying to tweak the code below but I can't figure out how to pass the HTML id to the javascript code. I know the getElementById() is not correct in that context and shouldn't be called. But I don't know how to carry the id value across into the Javascript function.

```
<script>
function CopyToClipboard(myInput) {
  /* Get the text field */
  var copyText = document.getElementById("myInput");

  /* Select the text field */
  copyText.select(myInput);

  /* Copy the text inside the text field */
  document.execCommand("copy");

  /* Alert the copied text */
  alert("Copied the text: " + copyText.value);
}
</script>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The error is that you use `document.getElementById("myInput")` instead of `document.getElementById(myInput)`.

Comment: I see! wasn't sure if it that function was refering to the variable itself or just its name. I didn't think much of it because I thought getElementById() was maybe not the right function to use in this context.Thank you.

Comment: @Bluz You're welcome! By the way, you do not need to pass any arguments to the `select()` function, so just use `copyText.select()`.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function CopyToClipboard(myInput) {
  /* Get the text field */
  var copyText = document.getElementById(myInput) // pass dynamic value here

console.log(copyText)
  /* Select the text field */
  copyText.select(myInput);

  /* Copy the text inside the text field */
  document.execCommand("copy");

  /* Alert the copied text */
  alert("Copied the text: " + copyText.value);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" size="70" value="something1" id="v1">
<button onclick="CopyToClipboard('v1')">Copy command</button>

<input type="text" size="70" value="something2" id="v2">
<button onclick="CopyToClipboard('v2')">Copy command</button>
```